# Which is the convention to place, name, and load model modules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, module, convention

I'm currenly doing the following:

```
app/models/
  user.rb
  finders/user_finders.rb
  attributes/user_attributes.rb
  validations/user_validations.rb
```

And so on for many "big" models.

And then, to load them I do the following:

In `app/models/user.rb`

```
load 'attributes/user_attributes.rb'
load 'finders/user_finders.rb'
load 'validations/user_validations.rb'
```

The user_{stuff}.rb just re-open the User class.

But the problem is that my user_{stuff} is loaded twice during production or test (not development though), and it breaks some stuff with aliasing.

Which is the Rails-way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

I use `concerned_with` to handle this situation - see [here](http://paulbarry.com/articles/2008/08/30/concerned-with-skinny-controller-skinny-model) - but there are issues with doing things this way - see the comments at the end of the article and [this piece](http://www.balagan.org.uk/software-development/ruby-on-rails/concerned_with-pattern.htm).  No doubt the best solution is to design your app so the models don't grow too big - but obviously this is not always how things work out, which is why I ended up using it of course.